# ggplot and scales package not calculating/printing percentages correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage

I was having trouble converting my bar chart to percentages (y-axis) and so have tried using the scales package. It worked, but the percentages that it is representing in the chart are not correct. I do not know what denominator it is using to determine the percentages. Does anyone know how/where to find this and check it or change it? Here is the code I'm using:

```
OSU_Pre_Student_Ex$employ <- factor(OSU_Pre_Student_Ex$employ, levels = 
c("Undergraduate student", "Pre-licensure student", "Master's student", "Doctoral student"))

OSU_Pre_Student_Ex$employ<-as.factor(OSU_Pre_Student_Ex$employ)
OSU_Pre_Student_Ex$employ = fct_infreq(OSU_Pre_Student_Ex$employ)

OSU_Pre_Student_Ex %>%
filter(!is.na(employ)) %>%

ggplot(aes(x =employ, fill= employ, drop.na = TRUE)) + 
geom_bar(show.legend = FALSE)+
xlab("Student type") + 
ylab("Percent") +
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100))+
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy=1, scale = 1))+

scale_fill_manual(values = BarGraphPalette5, drop = TRUE) + 

theme_minimal(base_family="Calibri")+

theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.2), panel.grid.minor = element_line(size= 0.1))+theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x 
=element_text(size=12),axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12))+
scale_x_discrete(limits = levels(OSU_Pre_Student_Ex$employ))
```

The output on my end (which visually looks good but the numbers are not):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIM1s.png)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. We can't currently run the code because we don't have the data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `scales::percent_format` will not compute any percentages for you. It will simply format numbers as percentages. As you are using `geom_bar` the numbers are simply the counts of your `employ` column.